# What is Commutative Replicated Data Type, and how does it do Replication without requiring consensus?

Tags: replication, distributed

I am trying to do research on Commutative Replicated Data Type, and do not find any good definitions that aren't mired down in a ton of technical terms that makes it hard to understand how this allows for replication of data in a distributed environment without using consensus.

Comment: what application are we talking about here? please clarify.

Comment: So far I've seen this implemented in Riak NoSQL Database.

Answer (score 1):

In Layman's terms you can think of CRDTs as follows:

CRDTS are a datatype to achieve strong eventual consistency in distributed environments without explicit synchronization. The attractive property of CRDTs is that they are both conflict-free and don't require synchronization, which is a bit confusing at first since you'd think there must be some sort of synchrony, e.g what happens if I write 2 and then 3 to the replicas and replica A receives update 3 before 2 and replica B receives the correct order, first 2 then 3, then we have a conflict?

The key to CRDT is that they are delimited to specific operations in which case the scenario above would not yield any conflict. The simplest scenario is to increment an aggregated value, if A and B just add all the incoming values they will both eventually end up with the value 5, without conflict, relying only on the weak assumptions of eventual consistency. Specifically the operation requirements are typically that the operations are commutative and that operations don't violate causal order.

Basically, CRDTs guarantees that all concurrent operations commute with each other.

Of course if CRDTs could just implement simple summation it would not be very interesting. However, it turns out that clever people have developed CRDT algorithms for more useful things such editing a shared document (see "CRDT Logoot"), grow-only sets, etc.

But still, bare in mind that by removing the need for Consensus, CRDTs are inherently limited and there are many simple things they cannot do.

Hope this description made any sense for you, for a more exact description I think the mathematical definition is the most intuitive.